# Joomla : social engineering content detected

Tags: joomla, phishing

Google is saying I have a social engineering content in my joomla 3 web site. This is the URL

plombier-chauffagistes[**DOT**]fr/ppp/79629b8a3ff4b34eb8db788c68d680ce/login.php?cmd=_login-run&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f1ff80d546411d7f8a8350c132bc41e0934cfc023d4e8f9e5

You can try to open this URL in google chrome : it will display an error :(
I can't fix the problem : the "ppp" folder does not exists, I made some rewrite rules in .htaccess, I also tried to delete .htaccess, but the problem still remains.

Comment: I would replace all of the Joomla files with a clean set of the current version, this includes any extensions you added.  Look for any unfamiliar files.  Then try to figure out how someone got access so you don't get this situation again. You can got the the Joomla stack exchange site for more help. [joomla.se]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to do when this thing happens is check the `.htaccess` file, which is most likely hacked.

The second thing would be to just overwrite your core Joomla files from those from a fresh Joomla install.

If you still have the problem, please post back here.

Comment: As as wrote, even with .htaccess deleted, the problem remains ! So I installed ClamAV and found 2 infected files, I deleted them and asked Google to recheck the site : he said it's clean now :) But Norton Safeweb find other problems I don't understand : https://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.plombier-chauffagistes.fr

Comment: Norton's scan results are typically cached - so wait around 24 hours and check to see if the problem is no more.

Comment: thanks :) is there any black box joomla vulnerability scanner ? like Wpscan for Wordpress